# I need to compare two arrays/state and get the data from the first array/state that doesn't match with the data on the second array - Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

So I'm working with states in React, and i want to compare the two arrays/state and get the data from the first array that doesn't match with the data on the second array.
The first array is a state, and the second one is an array. 
My first state/array looks like this = state : [ { id : id , productNumber : "productnumber"}... ] and the second array loos like this = array ["productnumber","productnumber"...],
and here what is my code's look like.

```
let newArray = [];

state.forEach(product=>{
    array.forEach(productNumber=>{
        if(product.productNumber !== productNumber){
            newArray = [...newArray,product.productNumber];
        }
    })
})
```

and it doesn't work, it stores all the data from the first array/state and even doubled it. I tried using nested if statements, still doesn't. I don't know what todo.

Comment: `let newArray = [];

state.forEach(product=>{
    if (!newArray.contains(product.productNumber)) {
        newArray.push(product.productNumber);
    }
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newArray = [];

state.forEach(({productNumber}) => {
  if (array.indexOf(productNumber) === -1) {
    newArray = [...newArray, productNumber];
  }
})
```

Or similarly, you can filter the state array and return the products with productNumber not in your second array.

```
const newArray = state.filter(({productNumber}) => array.indexOf(productNumber) === -1);
```